# clonar elementos html como selects, radiobuttons en angular 4

Tags: angular4, angular-directivas

Como se puede clonar elementos en angular 4? Los elementos de la plantilla del componente, por ejemplo:

```
<div>
aqui hay selects
radios y demas
<div>
```

Clonar toda la seccion del div con todo incluido. Existe jquery clone ya pero son plugins javascript. Segun se dice que es mejor no usar plugins js. Solo plugins que son para angular 4.

Comment: Quieres que ese <div> se repita varias veces? Utilizarlo en varios lugares distintos? Si podrías explayarte un poco mas, te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Si. que el div se copie varias veces. y todo lo de adentro

Comment: Puedes generar un componente con ese diseño y parámetros de entrada para los datos, o si es algo a menor escala, algo chico  que se repite X veces dependiendo de un contecto, un *ngFor en el <div> exterior.

Comment: El problema seria cuando son select, radios y demas elementos que consumen un json. Se tendria que consumir json siempre cada vez que se copien los elementos y si son muchos..

Comment: La directiva *ngFor que te menciona @FedericoMadoery es lo que estás buscando, esta se encarga de repetir (clonar) n veces el elemento y los hijos de este elemento. ¿Qué quieres decir con consumir JSON cada vez que se copien los elementos? Detalla más la pregunta, aparentemente la solución está en utilizar la directiva mencionada.

Comment: Me refiero a consumir un servicio, es decir traer datos de una base de datos por medio de un servicio por medio de angular. Acabo de encontrar otro problema y es que si se clona el elemento como seria la mejor forma de bindiarlo? osea con [(ngModel)] = "modelo"